403 Forbidden only on some files is unexplainable
I am working on a simple script that is supposed to upload an image contained in a folder to a Wordpress setup, using the Wordpress REST API. The script is running on a local install of MAMP.
For some reason, some images return a 403 error: Forbidden, access to this resource on the server is denied. But some others work. I haven't found a single common identifier that would explain why some files work and others don't, other than files downloaded from the internet seem to work best.
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";

$apiEndpoint = "https://mywebsite.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/media";

$file = file_get_contents( 'chronometer.png'); // This works with some images but not others, whether in a sub directory or not
$url = $apiEndpoint;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mywebsite.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/media" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="example.png"',
"Authorization: Basic MYKEY"
] );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

?>


I have been at this for hours with no success. Things I have tried so far:

Checking apache and php config to allow writing, reading
Changing file extensions to ".png" vs ".PNG", ".jpg" vs ".JPG"...
Creating a .htaccess to overwrite all httpd conf that might get in the way
Setting all folders, subfolders and files in the project root to read&write for everybody (I'm on Mac)
Checking file upload limits in php conf

Example of a file that works:
Chronometer
Example of a file that doesn't work:
Scene

Your working example image is a PNG, the not working one is a JPG ... Are you sending filename="example.png in the Content-Disposition header for both, or did you modify it accordingly for the JPG?

Also, no Content-Type header? That might be even more important, than the file name suffix.

I do modify the Content-Disposition for both sorry I forgot to mention that, and I'm not sure how Content-Type would interfere with file accessibility on the server side? The issue is simply that the file is not accessible. If I try with another file, it will work, or not. Seems random.

Oh, so you are talking about accessing the actual image files directly, after they have been uploaded. I was assuming this was about getting a 403 response from the Rest API endpoint. Do you see the images on the server, when you check via FTP? What are the file system access permissions set to? What do access and error log have to say?

Share the full error. If you don't see one in the response, take a look at your error logs.
